# Initializing an @groovy.transform.Field with Jenkins system variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins 2.1382.2.

In this, I am allowed to declare and initialize a field with a value in my Jenkinsfile:

```
@groovy.transform.Field final MY_FIELD = "Some Value";
```

But if I try this:

```
@groovy.transform.Field final MY_FIELD = "${JenkinsSystemVariable}";
```

where `JenkinsSystemVariable` is set under **Jenkins > Configure > Global properties**, I get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JenkinsSystemVariable for class: WorkflowScript`

I've tried `System.getProperty("JenkinsSystemVariable")` that this doesn't return the value (and requires me to add `java.lang.System.getPropery` to the approved scripts)

Is there another approach to this so I can scope the variable as a field?

The only other approach is to not make it final and dynamically assign the value, but I have other final fields that parse this one as well that would need to be refactored

---

EDIT: To elaborate (where JGP = Jenkins Global Property)

#### 1. JGP call outside of node, works fine

```
final myUrl = "${JenkinsSystemVariable}";
echo myUrl

node ("node-label") {
    stage("something") {
        echo myUrl
    }
}
```

Has no issue printing

#### 2. JGP Var, issue not defined in method scope

```
final myUrl = "${JenkinsSystemVariable}";
echo myUrl

def myMethod () {
    myUrl
}

node ("node-label") {
    stage("something") {
        println myMethod()
    }
}
```

#### 3. No JGP Var + annotation, almost but not the right value

```
@groovy.transform.Field final myUrl = "MyStringConstant";

def myMethod () {
    myUrl
}

node ("node-label") {
    stage("something") {
        println myMethod()
    }
}
```

## Workaround

Makes sure that the value is pulled from one location, just happens to be a dynamic method.

```
def myUrl() {
    "${JenkinsSystemVariable}"
}

def myMethod () {
    myUrl()
}

node ("node-label") {
    stage("something") {
        println myMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to access the full path to the system variable within its proper scope. I do not believe it is globally accessible as is, at least not without importing the relevant package (maybe?).

Comment: I have no clue how to find that "right package" without approving more things to the "in script" approvals. I want to avoid these as much as possible, so I may reject it if there another approach

Comment: Either that or start digging around in source code, because that thing is not documented.

Comment: Might just go with another workaround for now

Comment: You can't do that. Environment variables and parameters are only available within `pipeline` or `node` context, but fields are always initialized before. You have to remove `final` and assign to the field in `pipeline` or `node`.